# Spring REST basic authentication need User ID

Tags: spring, rest, basic-authentication

I got a simple REST Applikation with basic authentication.
The Authentication ist working whell and I can POST / GET my data.
But after authentication and reaching the Controller i need the username / password
to use it in my Controller.
Is it possible to get this from the Heades or something? or do I really need to POST/GET my data with username/password and ignoring the authentication ?
I thought it could be reused.

ThX fo your help.

Comment: Have you inspected the HttpRequest object?

Comment: No I will try, how can I call an instance of HttpRequest. My controller is a simple class registered by annotations.

Comment: OK i got the HttpRequest I will try to get some data out of it.

Comment: I get the HttpServletRequest Object, couse if I try to get the HttpRequest, it couse an exception. I get the attributes from this object but there are no credentials which I use to authenticate while using my rest interface. hmmm

Comment: Ok... I'm a bit confused... you are using Basic Auth, what is doing the Basic Auth? Is it Apache? Is it your Java container? Is it Spring Security (which would be optimal)? If it's Spring Security, then you would automatically be authenticated (and authorized).

Comment: hmm exactly it calls "http basic authentication". I'm using spring RestTemplate on my client side (Android). Just put user & password to HttpAuthentication -> HttpHeaders -> HttpEntity and use the RestTemplate.exchange(...) method to send my data to the server. On the server there I use <http-basic/> and authentication-manager / provider to secure my rest api. The authentication is working well I just need the user and password in my controller again.

Comment: Yes it's Spring Security. After the authentication I need to know who use the REST API couse the user send data which will be stored in a database. My idea was to identify the user by authentication and know its needed foreign key for data storing. In this way I wannt the user just to send his data without any user object for the database...

Comment: ... Eg. usually I do something like this: sendData(user, data), but wannt something like this: sendData(data). After the authentication I wannt to get the database ID by the auth. credentials and store the data. Otherway I send the user / password for auth. and again the same in an "user" object. Is there a general approach to do this??

Answer (score 0):

You can use the @RequestHeader annotation in your REST method.

One more option is to use the HttpServletRequest which could be autowired into your controller, then get the header data using the getHeader method ([eg](http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-get-http-request-header-in-java/))

Comment: thx I get the objects but still can't get the user & pass out of the HttpAuthentication *scratch*

Comment: Would you mind to paste the code which does the REST call on you client side?

Answer (score 0):

OK it was really simple, just need to do this in your controller:`SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getName();`
This way I got my username. The Password is null couse of version 3.1 but I think I wouldn't need it.
ThX to all trying to help me :)

Answer (score 0):

```
protected HttpHeaders getAuthentificatedRequestHeaders(String aUsername, String aPassword) {

    HttpAuthentication authHeader = new HttpBasicAuthentication(aUsername, aPassword);
    HttpHeaders httpHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
    httpHeaders.setAuthorization(authHeader);
    List<MediaType> media = new ArrayList<MediaType>();
    media.add(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
    httpHeaders.setAccept(media);
    return httpHeaders;
}
```

public UserMdl getUserById(long id)
    {

```
    final String url = getResourceUrl("user/{id}");
    HttpEntity<?> requestEntity = new HttpEntity<Object>(getAuthentificatedRequestHeaders(Config.REST_USERNAME, Config.REST_PASSWORD));
    RestTemplate restTemplate = getRestTemplatWithJsonConverter();
    ResponseEntity<UserMdl> response = restTemplate.exchange(url,HttpMethod.GET, requestEntity, UserMdl.class, id);
    UserMdl user = response.getBody();

    return user;
}
```

This ist some code I use in my Android client. The "getAuthentificatedRequestHeades(..)" method is a part of an abstract class and is used for all requests. The other method is using the code than..